# SignalR wth gzip compression

Tags: signalr

Having some problem developing a SignalR client for a Hub hosted in asp.net website with gzip compression enabled. Since we are using IIS compression, the response from SignalR also gets compressed, but, the client does not understand the response and we get a Json parsing error on the client side.

SignalR internally uses `HttpWebRequest` to make make http requests and `HttpWebRequest` can be configured to automatically decompress the response using `AutomaticDecompression` property. So, if somehow I can get hold of the `HttpWebRequest` object used by SignalR to make the request, I should be able to set the enable automatic decompression.

I thought I should be able to get access to the `HttpWebRequest` by providing `HubConnection.Start` with my custom implementation of `IHttpClient`, `IHttpClient.GetAsync` takes a `prepareRequest` action which I thought should give me access to the `HttpWebRequest`, but, `HttpHelper.GetAsync` wraps the `HttpWebRequest` with `HttpWebRequestWrapper` before passing to `prepareRequest` and `HttpWebRequestWrapper` does not provide access to `HttpWebRequest`.

`HttpHelper` class is internal so can't use it as well, so, I am not exactly sure how to enable automatic decompression with SignalR.

I can expose the `HttpWebRequest` in `HttpWebRequestWrapper`, but, would prefer a simpler solution if one exists. Any thougths?

I am using SignalR version 0.5.1.10822

My auto decompression HttpClient:

```
public class HttpClientWithAutoDecompression : IHttpClient
{
    readonly DefaultHttpClient _httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    private readonly DecompressionMethods _decompressionMethods;
    public HttpClientWithAutoDecompression(DecompressionMethods decompressionMethods)
    {
        _decompressionMethods = decompressionMethods;
    }

    public Task<IResponse> GetAsync(string url, Action<IRequest> prepareRequest)
    {
        Task<IResponse> task = _httpClient.GetAsync(url, 
            request =>
                {
                    [ERROR: request is actually HttpRequestWrapper and
                     does not expose HttpWebRequest]**              ] 
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) request; 
                    httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = _decompressionMethods;
                    prepareRequest(request);
                });

        return task.ContinueWith(response =>
        {
            Log.Debug(this, "Response: {0}", response.Result.ReadAsString());
            return response.Result;
        });

    }
....
}
```

Comment: I've now checked on a server that also has gzip compression enabled and found out that SignalR.Client doesn't send Accept-Encoding: gzip by default, so my server responds with an uncompressed message and everything works as expected. It appears that either your client incorrectly sends the Accept-Encoding header or your sever forces every response to gzip (which the built-in IIS compression does not). Can you check with Fiddler what's going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge GZip encoding and streaming do not mix. In the case of the forever frame transport the client wouldn't be able to decode any on the streaming content until the entire response, or at least a significant block of data, is received (due to the way the data is decoded). In the case of web sockets there is not support for encoding of any kind at this time, although there is apparently an extension to the specification for per message encoding [being worked on](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-tyoshino-hybi-permessage-compression-00.txt).

That said, if you wanted to attempt to provide support for the LongPolling transport, the only way I can see this being possible is to provide your own SignalR `IHttpClient` implementation. You can see right now that the `DefaultHttpClient` class uses `HttpHelper::GetAsync` which creates the `HttpWebRequest` internally and you can never get your hands on that because you only have access to the `IRequest` which is `HttpWebRequestWrapper` at that point.

By creating your own `IHttpClient` you can take over the initial instantiation of the `HttpWebRequest`, set the `AutomaticDecompression` and then wrap that up yourself with the `HttpWebRequestWrapper`.

Comment: But it should work with the longPolling transport, as the long running request gets completed when returning a message to the client, or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks huys, I understand that why compression won't work with streaming, I think my main problem was that the SingnalR Api interface does not give you access to the HttpWebRequest that it uses to make the request, basically I wanted to update the `httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression` property, but, SignalR wraps the 'httpWebRequest' in a wrapper which does not expose the AutomaticDecompression property. dfowler suggested that I modify the wrapper class and rebuild SignalR. For now I am just using reflection to access the private property I need access to.

Comment: @akoeplinger Yes, it should work with LP transport. Of course that's the worst transport to use efficiency wise, so it probably negates any potential benefit of gzip unless your message payloads happen to be huge.

Comment: Thanks Drew, just a note: you can create your own IHttpClient but you will have to implement your own HttpHelper::GetAsync as well, because HttpHelper is internal, so you can not use this in your assembly. Therefore I created a wrapper over DefaultHttpClient and used reflection to get access to _request.

FieldInfo requestField = typeof (HttpWebRequestWrapper).GetField("_request", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) requestField.GetValue(request);
httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

Comment: @FaisalMansoor You don't need HttpHelper, that's just an internal implementation detail of SignalR really. You can just do your own instantiation of HttpWebRequest right inline in your IHttpClient if you wanted to. And as for reflection.... no comment. :P