# Can I tweak Json.NET to write directly to a compressed stream?

Tags: c#, json

I'm using SignalR to transfer large amounts of data.
To reduce bandwidth, I was wondering if it was possible to have Json.NET (which is the serializer SignalR uses) serialize the data to a compressed stream?

Ideally, I'd like this to work:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new MyJsonConverter());


public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // Tweak the writer to have it compress the data
        writer.WritePropertyName("Meaning");
        writer.WriteValue(42);
    }

}
```

Of course I'm open to any other suggestions to reduce bandwidth

Comment: This might be related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717101/signalr-wth-gzip-compression

Comment: Thanks @Pierre-LoupPagniez , I read that post and my conclusion was that SignalR doesn't support compression out of the box and I have to solve it in the application level

Comment: You can use the `JsonTextWriter` class to create a `JsonWriter` out of any `TextWriter`. If you have a way of getting a `TextWriter` which automatically does data compression, then you can use that.

Comment: @TannerSwett True, but as far as I know I can't control the `JsonWriter` passed to `WriteJson`. I can create my own but that would require going over the data twice (serializing + compressing)